# Vagrant+PyCharm: How to edit files which are outside the mapped directory?

Tags: pycharm, vagrant

I use PyCharm Professional with Vagrant support.

Editing my files works fine. My files are on my local machined and "mapped/mounted" into the Vagrant machine.

But if I go to the declaration of a file which is outside the mapped directory, PyCharm opens a cached version. For example the django source code is outside the mapped directory:

[image: vagrant-remote-file]

`/home/guettli/.cache` is on my local machine, not inside Vagrant.

If I edit this (for example I add `assert 0, value_which_i_want_to_see`), then this change is not active, since the original file did not change.

How to edit the files with PyCharm which are outside the Vagrant mapped directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pycharm` and `Vagrant` directory should be one and the same, meaning your project directory, like:

Both of them use caching, but you shouldn't care about those. Basically (in this case `projects` is just a convention, can be any path you want and usually use): `/home/<userid>/projects/<your-project>`, inside of which you have your `src` for your `python` code and `Vagrantfile` for your Vagrant machine definition. Then, to access your python code inside your VM, spawn up by `Vagrant` using probably VirtualBox as a Hypervisor, you may `mount` your desired directory in your desired path.

So in this case, the files you have part of your PyCharm **project** (i.e. editor view) are the same files within your parent `/home/<userid>/projects/<your-project>` and executed by your process inside the VM managed by Vagrant.

Comment: For my code it works fine, since these files live on my machine (they are mounted in vagrant via Vagrantfile). But the external libraries are not on my machine.

Comment: external libraries are being added to the project, with the correct, right version that you use. This was pycharm will NOT use the files from the VM, but the one PyCharm can download, reference by downloading them directly locally, in the cache, but that's a Config. to your project. So, by just adding the dependency, PyCharm should be able to download those dependencies. If you want to have dependencies directly the files from the VM disk, you have to mount (probably as a different folder) that specific folder too, then use external libraries, with relative path to your new local dir.